# Get sentences from Gutenberg texts in Python

Tags: python, regex, text

I'm trying to parse 100 of the Project Gutenberg texts for an NLP task, e.g. ["H. G. Wells' War of the Worlds"](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/36/pg36.txt). I'm trying to write a Python script to output a list of sentences for each text. How can I ignore the headers and footers of the Gutenberg texts to extract the actual book text into sentences?

Comment: You can use the HTML version instead of TXT and only parse text between `<p>` and `</p>` tags.

Comment: It looks as if even the plain text version has `*** START ...` and `*** END ...` delimiters in the document to separate the book content from the project gutenberg headers/footers.